# How to optimize a query that uses a multi statement table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlperformance

so I have a query that is taking several seconds to run.

```
SELECT it.invoiceID, SUM(xgtpp.total + ws.expense) AS invoice_total
FROM Invoices_Timesheets it (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Timesheets_WorkSegments tws (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN WorkSegments ws (NOLOCK) ON (tws.worksegmentID = ws.ID)
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT gtpp.worksegmentID, SUM(gtpp.pay_per_shift) AS total
        FROM dbo.fnGetTotalPerProject(ws.projectID) gtpp
        WHERE (gtpp.worksegmentID = tws.worksegmentID)
        GROUP BY gtpp.worksegmentID
    ) xgtpp
ON (it.timesheetID = tws.timesheetID)
WHERE it.invoiceID = 37
GROUP BY it.invoiceID
```

The tables used are:

```
[Invoices]
ID,companyID,userID,projectID,insertDate,submitDate,viewDate,tax

[Invoices_Timesheets]
ID,timesheetID,invoiceID

[WorkSegments]
ID,companyID,userID,projectID,insertDate,startTime,endTime,break,poa,deleteDate,expense

[Timesheets_WorkSegments]
ID,timesheetID,worksegmentID
```

The UDF `dbo.fnGetTotalPerProject()` accepts only one parameter `projectID`

When I replace `ws.projectID` inside the UDF with a static value the performance is incredible, but as soon as I make it use `ws.projectID` the performance slows down badly.

This query is a sub-query of a larger one, but it is definitely the bottle neck.

Comment: Can you rewrite the UDF to take two arguments, `projectID` and `worksegmentID` ?

Comment: I am sure it is possible, but the UDF is being used in a bunch of places, so re-writing it is not really advisable.

Comment: Can you post that function? Also you really shouldn't be littering your database with those NOLOCK hints unless accuracy and consistency isn't important. I am guessing by the nature of the table names that accuracy is important here. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Just posted the UDF above. In regards to the NOLOCKs , they could be removed. It was left there from the previous developer.

Comment: Yikes. That UDF is definitely the problem. It is a multi statement table valued function. The performance of this is generally even worse than scalar functions. Table valued functions are best when they are inline, meaning a single statement. There are literally dozens of things inside there that are problematic. Selecting the same row from the same table over and over, TOP 1 with no order by, table variables, recursive ctes, the list can go on here for a bit. This is in serious need of a total rewrite.

Comment: TOP 1 selects all have an ORDER BY... fyi... but in general yes it is true that the UDF is quite ugly. The performance of the UDF on the other hand is pretty impressive. Anyway, the UDF is not the bottle neck that I need to resolve at this time, the sub query is.

Comment: Line 123 has an select top 1 as a column in an insert and there is no order by. As for the performance I don't know there is much you can do because you are returning a ton of rows from the function and then aggregating the results.

Comment: You replaced the UDF call with constants and it got fast. That's a good test to get started but it's not really meaningful because you have to call the UDF! The `CROSS APPLY` is not the problem. That's just a join. The UDF (somehow) is the problem. Post the actual execution plan. Maybe we can't do anything as long as you insist on calling that UDF...

Comment: When I replace ws.projectID with a static number the performance is excellent. Maybe where is a way to utilize this fact to rewrite the sub-query some how?

Comment: But you need to call that UDF! That's what causes the perf drop. In the exec plan, that I'm sure you are going to post, we will find a loop join to that UDF. It is opaque to the optimizer. Nothing can be done.

Comment: How many worksheets are there per project. We actually need to call the UDF only one per project, not once per worksheet... Maybe I was too quick and something can be done.

Comment: There can be many worksegments in a project as each worksegment is an interval with start & end time

Comment: I am not sure how to post the execution plan in here.. I have an option to save it as .sqlplan. Is that what you meant?

Comment: That would work. Upload on pastebin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89425/discussion-between-artknight-and-usr).

Comment: Lets jump on the chat

Comment: fyi, i cannot upload to pastebin as the content is larger than 512 KB

Comment: I can tell you what I am seeing though... For "table valued function [fnGetTotalPerProject] [gtpp]" cost is 0%

Comment: Removing the UDF code from the question doesn't really help, that's the source of your problem, not the code that is now included.

Comment: I added the UDF back in.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-writing the `dbo.fnGetTotalPerProject` to be per timesheet rather than per project. My next goal is to optimize it per work segment.